# Sourcing a stored file and writing to output file in godbolt

Tags: c++, godbolt

I would like to modify the example provided by godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/WseTsM8YG to create a project that reads from `Isource.json` input file and writes to `Osource.json` with all of the json files created and stored on the godbolt website/project itself.

I have gotten to https://godbolt.org/z/Ecxz6abEn but the code does not compile let alone allowing me to create the `Isource.json` file.

The code compiles and works fine on my local computer. The code is:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
using namespace boost::json;
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::string fname = "Isource.json";
    //Read JSON file and store in json::object
    const path fileName(fname);
    object obj;
    std::ifstream file(fname);
    std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
    value jv = parse(content);
    obj = jv.as_object();
    file.close();
        
    //Output to OSource.json
    fname = "Osource.json";
    std::ofstream ofile(fname);
    ofile << boost::json::value_from(obj);
    ofile.close();

}
```

I do not want this to be a `cmake` project and would like to build it using standard traditional g++ makefile. How can one create the needed `Isource.json` file and have godbolt create the output file (`Osource.json`) that can also be seen on the website itself? On my Windows computer using Visual Studio, I would store `Isource.json` in the same folder where the project/solution file exists and the above code would read that file and `Osource.json` would be created/written in the same folder.

Comment: I don't think you can. Note that the first example provided (a CMake project, quite "standard" these days) doesn't create nor write to any file other than `stdout`.

Comment: @Bob__ Ah I see. So, one can only read from a file stored on godbolt, but cannot write to the project space. I suppose the thought was ... what if someone were to write a huge file? But one could also store a huge input file. I am only guessing that the latter is more/easier to manage / control / prevent than the former. Would you happen to know how to create an input file on godbolt? How does one create an actual/logical /resource/ folder, for instance within which to store hello.txt as the first example does?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028715/include-external-header-file-for-c-on-compiler-explorer or the [FAQ](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/wiki/FAQ) about including a file from an url.