# Is there a way to add header file to godbolt.org?

Tags: c++, godbolt

Am I correct that the only way to add my own C++ header file on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is to copy/paste its content to the source C++ file?

Comment: If it's not one of the headers available (in the compiler window's "Libraries" option), then yes.

Comment: @TobySpeight, it is hard to imagine that "my own C++ header file" becomes a part of the Library, so I get this as "yes" and it is OK to just copy/paste file, since no better options are available. Is it correct?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028715/include-external-header-file-for-c-on-compiler-explorer) Godbolt supports projects with multiple files and CMake. I haven't tried but maybe this feature can help to use external headers.

Comment: You can include http:// links to header files on i.e. GitHub.

Comment: look at [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T8zcdexdz)